# Is there a way to deploy and use multiple versions of a shared flow in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

We are using Apigee sharedflows as shared libraries for common functions across our org. But versioning has been a challenge as we have not found a way to support multiple versions during build and deployment. 
The `SharedFlowBundle` in the `Flowcallout` does not appear to accept a version
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/flow-callout-policy#request.

1. Is there way to deploy multiple active versions of a shared flow?
2. If so, how can we specify the version in the SharedFlowBundle tag in the FlowCallout policy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apigee shared flows are a *lot* like the API proxies entity, in how they are versioned and deployed. Only one revision can be deployed to an org's environment at a time. So you can have v3.1 deployed to Stage (environment) while v3.0 is deployed to Prod, but you can't have both v3.1 and v3.0 deployed simultaneously to your Prod environment. You could forks the shared flow though, effectively creating to separate (identical) shared flows, but then you have more management overhead to manage if you want different versions accessible at the same time in the same environment. Perhaps a better alternative would be to modify your shared flow to exhibit different behaviors depending on its input, so you can support your use-cases with one shared flow bundle.

Comment: Modifying our shared flow to exhibit different behaviors was not possible due to the limitation that flows can only have Steps not Flows, so we are currently using the different versions approach that you mention - using version in the names -  sharedFlow_v1, sharedFlow_v2, etc.